# TypeAhead Autocomplete Not WOrking after Second Character is typed and css looks broken

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

Here is my JS with typeahead 0.10.0 with bootstrap 3 and Asp.net MVC 5

```
var jobCodes = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function (d) { return d.JobName; },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: "/api/jobservice/getjobcodes"
});

jobCodes.initialize();

$('#jobquery').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'job-codes',
    displayKey: 'JobName',
    source: jobCodes.ttAdapter()
});
```

Here is a sample of my JSON data that comes back:

```
[{"JobCodeId":101,"JobName":"Agricultural Sciences\r"},{"JobCodeId":102,"JobName":"Animal Sciences\r"},{"JobCodeId":103,"JobName":"Plant & Soil Sciences\r"}]
```

**First Problem I have is when I type first character i do see suggestions but no css for box like in typeahead example am I missing any css?**

[image]

**Second problem is when i type 2nd character suggestions go away as you can see in the screen shot below.**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem when I entered the second character, but I updated the Bloodhound datumTokenizer from this:

```
datumTokenizer: function (d) { return d.TagName; },
```

... to this:

```
datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.TagName); },
```

I'm not sure what the `Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace` does but it did the trick for me.

As for the CSS, I used this [stylesheet](https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less) based on this [issue](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/378) - but I found out it doesn't work with the latest version of typeahead.js

Comment: i tired that return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace but still is not working same results.

Comment: Update: For css issues with bootstrap, use https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less

Answer (score 2):

For your first problem, the DOM structure of the typeahead generated in v0.10 is different from what's generated in previous versions. Make sure your CSS is updated accordingly.

For your second problem, both `datumTokenizer` and `queryTokenizer` are expected to return an array of tokens (i.e. strings). However your `datumTokenizer` just returns a string. Depending on the behavior you want, I have 2 suggestions:

If you only want suggestions to show for full string matches, do the following:

```
var jobCodes = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function (d) { return [d.JobName]; },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: "/api/jobservice/getjobcodes"
});
```

Or if you'd like suggestions to show for word matches, try this:

```
var jobCodes = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.nonword(d.JobName); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  prefetch: "/api/jobservice/getjobcodes"
```

});

Comment: where can i find the example for css? i cannot seem to find it anywhere in the github repo for typeahead.